# Parsing Ethernet Frames and Data Types

Tags: c, sockets, typedef, raw-sockets

I have the seemingly simple task of printing very basic information regarding frames passing through a specific ethernet interface. I have a socket defined as

```
if ((sd = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL))) == -1) return __LINE__;
strcpy(ifr.ifr_name, argv[1]);
if (ioctl(sd, SIOCGIFFLAGS, &ifr) == -1) return __LINE__;
ifr.ifr_flags |= IFF_PROMISC;
if (ioctl(sd, SIOCSIFFLAGS, &ifr) == -1) return __LINE__;
if (ioctl(sd, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr) == -1) return __LINE__;
```

I loop my input like so

```
while (active) {
        FD_SET(sd, &fds);
        FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &fds);
        if ((rv = select(sd + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv)) < 0)
            active = 0;
        if (FD_ISSET(sd, &fds)) input(sd, buf);
```

This is where I am having problems. I define the ethernet header each frame is cast into with a `struct`

```
struct ethheader {
    unsigned char       dsta[6];
    unsigned char       srca[6];
    uint16_t            type;
};
```

And output the information like

```
void input(int sd, char *buf) {
    int i;
    char *p = buf;
    struct ethheader *eth = (struct ethheader*)buf;
    int len = read(sd, buf, BUF_SIZ);
    if (len < sizeof(struct ethheader)) {
        printf("smaller than an ethernet frame\n");
        return;
    } else {
        char dst[18];
        char src[18];
        for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            sprintf(dst + i * 3, "%02x:", eth->dsta[i]);
            sprintf(src + i * 3, "%02x:", eth->srca[i]);
        }
        dst[17] = '\0';
        src[17] = '\0';
        printf("dst: %s src: %s ", dst, src);
        switch (eth->type) {
        case 0x0800:
            printf("IPv4\n");
            break;
        case 0x0842:
            printf("ARP\n");
            break;
        case 0x86DD:
            printf("IPv6\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("unknown\n");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The output i receive indicates I am properly printing MAC addresses, I am not properly detecting protocols. I am pretty sure the bug deals with either lvalue byte sizes, or endian order-ness; or both. And it is at this point I feel compelled to ask here how I can better define my `struct`s values, and why my protocol `switch` is broken?

OK so after reading some comments, I was able to properly read the ethernet type:

```
struct ethheader {
    unsigned char       dsta[6];
    unsigned char       srca[6];
    unsigned char       type[2];
};
int type = (eth->type[0] << 8) + eth->type[1];
```

My secondary question remains: How can I better define these `struct`s with more portable types; or am I fine with `unsigned char`?

Comment: Use correct serialisation technique, not error-prone and non-portable casting.

Comment: @Olaf Will you elaborate on that?

Comment: Sorry, no. Using a search engine really is a skill which can be presumed nowadays. I gave you one keyword already.

Comment: @Olaf OK Thanks. I'm perusing some information already.

Comment: A `struct` declaration tells you nothing about the binary format of the data. It is implementation-specific at best, and undefined behavior at worst, and has no place in portable code. IOW, you can't use C `struct` declarations to unmarshall binary data. You have to manipulate each input byte explicitly to extract the data you need: yes, you **do** need to read individual bytes to reconstitute words of various lengths, etc.

Comment: @KubaOber Thanks! I am now able to read the frame type from the ethernet header using your advice (see my edit at the end of my question).

Comment: Get rid of the structs. They are unnecessary. Index into the packet using byte offsets, and reconstitute your data that way. Factor out reconstitution of each component into a separate function. E.g. `char * getMAC(char * src, MAC *)` would populate a `typedef struct {...} MAC`, and return the advanced buffer pointer. Thus `p = getMAC(p, dsta); p = getMAC(p, srca);` would extract the MACs.

Comment: @KubaOber Ooh! Those are really great ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you include `<net/ethernet.h>` you'll have `struct ether_header`:

```
struct ether_header
{
  u_int8_t  ether_dhost[ETH_ALEN];      /* destination eth addr */
  u_int8_t  ether_shost[ETH_ALEN];      /* source ether addr    */
  u_int16_t ether_type;                 /* packet type ID field */
} __attribute__ ((__packed__));
```

There are library functions you might want to use like:

```
   #include <netinet/ether.h>

   char *ether_ntoa(const struct ether_addr *addr);
```

Have you considered using [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/)?  It really makes these things easy.

(like getting a tachikoma to do the work for you :)